# US H-1B visa; will it be rejected if I am divorced?

Tags: usa, visa, marriage, divorce

Background: I, an Indian citizen, got married in 2017 in India. I became separated from my spouse within a few months. I didn't have a marriage certificate at that time, due to which my marital status is not mentioned in my passport.
Later I got legally divorced in 2023. Now while applying for an H-1B visa, I'm putting actual status "divorced" and the date of marriage 2017 and divorce 2023. I have a court decree to support this.
Question: will they reject my visa?

Comment: I think you mean H-1B visa? Why would a divorce affect an H-1B visa? It's employment based not marriage based or anything.

Comment: For completeness, where did the marriage take place and are you a citizen of that country?

Comment: Married in India, citizen of India

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your past marriage has no bearing on your H1b eligibility, neither positive nor negative. They will not reject your visa application just because you've been divorced.

Comment: Thanks for the information